# conditional operator usage

Tags: c++

Consider the following statement. What will be the value stored in b?

```
int a=1;
int b = a+=1 ? a+=1 : 10;
```

I get the answer as 4. Can anyone explain how that works please.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: "Can anyone explain how that works please." >> I certainly can't, ask the programmer who wrote it. And don't ever ask him to write anything again. :)

Comment: +1. It shows that you can code brainfuck in any language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has to do with precedence. If you examine the following code (with the rightmost `a+=1` changed for simplicity):

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    int a=1;
    int b = a+=1 ? 7 : 10;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

you will see that the output is `8`, not `7` or `10`.

That's because the statement:

```
    int b = a+=1 ? 7 : 10;
```

is being interpreted as:

```
    int b = (a += (1 ? 7 : 10));
```

Now, applying that to your case, we get:

```
    int b = (a += (1 ? a += 1 : 10));
```

and, in order of execution:

- the rightmost `a += 1` (since `1` is true) sets `a` to `2`.
- the leftmost `a += 2` (`2` is the result of the previous step) sets `a` to `4`.
- `b = 4` (`4` is the result of the previous step).

Just keep in mind that you can't necessarily rely on that order of evaluation. Even though there is a sequence point at the `?` (so that `1` is evaluated fully before continuing), there is no sequence point between the rightmost `a += ...` and the leftmost `a += ...`. And modifying a single variable twice without an intervening sequence point is undefined behaviour, which is why `gcc -Wall` will give you the very useful message:

```
warning: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined
```

That fact that it gives you `4` is pure coincidence. It could just as easily give you `3`, `65535` or even format your hard disk to teach you a lesson :-)

Comment: @shreedhar : Yes I have deleted my comment. This answer seems to be correct.

Comment: BTW g++ gives me a warning "operation on `a` may be undefined".

Comment: @Prasoon: That's because `a += a += 1` is undefined.

Comment: you just showed that b = 4, then how come the program should output 8?

Comment: @Felix, the program that output 8 is not the same as the one the OP gave us. I provided a different piece of code that changed the rightmost `a+=1` to `7`, just to illustrate the point that the order in which components of the expression was not what the OP thought. Then I plugged that little snippet of knowledge back into the OP's code to explain why it output 4. Changed answer to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the other answers these two code snippets are equivalent due to the grammar rules of C++ which determine how compound expressions must be parsed.

```
int a=1;
int b = a+=1 ? a+=1 : 10;
```

and

```
int a=1;
int b = (a += (1 ? (a += 1) : 10));
```

Although there is a sequence point in a *conditional-expression* it is between the evaluation of the first expression (`1`) and the evaluation of whichever one of the second and third expressions is evaluated (`a += 1` in this case). There is no explicit extra sequence point after the evaluation of the second or third expression.

This means that `a` is modified twice in the initializer for `b` without an intervening sequence point so the code has *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

Assembly analysis:

```
int main() 
{
    int a=1;
    int b = a+=1 ? a+=1 : 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Assembly code generated (using MinGW) for the above code is shown below. The comments are mine, of course! Read the comments also!

```
 call ___main        //entering into main()
 movl $1, 12(%esp)   //int a = 1; means 12(%esp) represents a;
 incl 12(%esp)       //a+=1 ; a becomes 2
 movl 12(%esp), %eax //loading 'a' onto a register(eax); eax becomes 2 
 addl %eax, %eax     //adding the register to itself; eax becomes 4
 movl %eax, 12(%esp) //updating 'a' with the value of eax; 'a' becomes 4
 movl 12(%esp), %eax //this step could be optimized away; anyway it loads value of 'a' onto the register(eax); eax becomes 4, in fact even earlier it was 4 too! needless step!
 movl %eax, 8(%esp)  //loading the value of eax at another memory location which is 8(%esp); this location represents b; 
 movl $0, %eax       //making eax zero! the return value of main()!
 leave               //now main() says, please leave me!
```

`12(%esp)` represent memory location of `a` , and at a distance 4 byte from it, that is, `8(%esp)` represents `b`.   **At the end, the value at both these memory locations is 4.**

**Hence, b = 4. Also a = 4.**